# Extend WiFi range of build in access point

Tags: pi-3, wifi, connection

We're using our Raspberry Pi 3 to control some music and lighting over it's access point with a smartphone - completely offline, on a handcart. Now we have connection problems when we're getting to far away from our Pi (like 10-20 meters). Is there some practical solution we could use for our problem? Like some extender or antenna?

We have no internet on that WiFi, it's just used to get a connection from our smartphones to the handcart.

Comment: Is the handcar metal?  Guessing, you might be able to make the surface into an [antenna ground plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_plane#Radio_antenna_theory).  On the other hand, that may be your problem.  Like I said, guessing.

Comment: Yup, it got a metal construction and the walls are made of wood. You've done that already once? A WiFi ground plane antenna?

Comment: It was the next step I was going to take / experiment with.  Fortunately relocating the WIFI radios work.  You might also look at [this stackexchange answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43312/add-an-external-antenna-to-a-pi-3).