# How can I receive sensor data from my raspberry pi when it is far away from any wifi?

Tags: networking, wifi, sensor, data-transfer

Let's say I want to use a raspberry pi for a research project. The raspberry pi would be placed in a secure case(power has been taken care of and is not an issue). However, it will be in the middle of a desert more than 50 mi away from wifi or cellular.

What would be my best solution to receiving data from the raspberry pi? Is there some sort of antenna setup that can broadcast a signal far enough to be picked up by me at my house that is about 50 mi away?

Comment: your question is not a RPi question ... it is a remote communication question

Comment: It is a similar question to this one, which has a score of 34. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43312/add-an-external-antenna-to-a-pi-3?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: What about a gsm module?

Comment: @BitcoinM:  Good catch!  :)

Comment: @BitcoinM: I think your range requirement (50 mi) will push you beyond the "practical" realm of wifi. The 2.4 GHz carrier freq will have more losses than lower freq bands. But good news is in stock for RPi: Google "software defined radio raspberry pi", and [check out this site.](https://www.rtl-sdr.com/)

Comment: @BitcoinM, the "similar" question that you reference asks if you can add an antenna to the RPI3 board .... it is a direct RPi question that is not similar to yours at all

Comment: @jsotola: Yes, it is, but with RPIs finding myriad applications in SDR, it seems irrelevant whether or not an antenna is mentioned as part of the question. Every rf device must have an antenna - how is that a discriminator?

Comment: @Seamus, the antenna is not a discriminator ... the discriminator is the fact that one question is about modifying an RPi and the other is not

Comment: @BitcoinM: You may find this [wiki from osmo-fl2k](https://osmocom.org/projects/osmo-fl2k/wiki/Osmo-fl2k) interesting. Pay particular attention to the paragraph on "Legal Aspects" at the `tail`.

Answer (score 3):

satcomm module

cost: $250
monthly fee: $15

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13745

[image]